# Dynamic view creation in iOS

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I have deleted my storyboard. I have `viewcontroller.h` and `viewcontroller.m` file and also added another view controller called `nextviewcontroller.h` and `nextviewcontroller.m`.

I want to create a dynamic button in viewcontroller and then if I click that button it should move to the next viewcontroller.

I can create dynamic view and button in the first viewcontroller but I'm not able to do so in the second viewcontroller.

Comment: Post the code you currently have and a specific problem that you are having with it.

Comment: Viewcontroller                   viewcontroller *view=[viewcontroller alloc]init;            UIbutton *but=[uIbutton buttonwithtype:UIbutton roundedrect] [self.view addsubview:but].   How to create view for next viewcontroller...

Comment: Pls provide answer anybody....

Comment: pls provide understandable question with detail and code, much more code. Just throw away this question its so little content, and write a new one with lots of info.

Comment: i want to move from one viewcontroller to nextviewcontroller without using storyboard......

Comment: appdelegate.h   ViewController *view;      appdelegate.m   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  view = [[ViewController alloc]init];
self.window.rootViewController = view;        viewcontroller.m    - (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender
{
    NextViewController *next = [[NextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NextViewController"bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:next animated:YES    completion:Nil];
   
}        error:nil modal viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me as if you want to implement your own "Container View Controller" in which case I recommend you read about this from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW13).

"**I want to create a dynamic button in viewcontroller and then if I click that button it should move next view controller**"

I assume you want the parent to know you want to move to another view, correct? I'll put an example on github.